# HP ambient light sensor adjustment

Tags: laptop, brightness, hp-laptop

I have an HP nc4400 running Windows 7 64 bit.

If I have the ambient light sensor enabled, it works well, but, its slightly too dim.

I can turn off the light sensor and turn up the brightness manually and its more than bright enough.

When I go to the brightness settings in Windows I can make the screen dimmer with the ambient light sensor enabled but cannot make it as bright as if it is disabled.

So my question is, is it possible to keep the light sensor enabled but configure it so that the screen is brighter for given "ambient light".

At the moment I have to turn it off whenever I'm in the office or outside in sunlight as I need the screen as bright as possible and it seems no matter how light it is, it never goes to full brightness when it's enabled.

Comment: I found those Ambient Light Sensors not very useful, I suggest you to turn it off and adjust the brightness manually.

Answer (score 1):

[Looks like you're not alone.](http://forum.notebookreview.com/showthread.php?t=350175)  That thread includes discussion of a program that may be able to control the brightness, although that's with the ambient sensor turned off.  It looks like they limit the max brightness to preserve battery life.